# JavaDoc overview description on top of output

Tags: java, javadoc

In JavaDoc, i can add a overview page, given as an externally created HTML (-overview option).
But the behavior of JavaDoc is, to show only the first sentence on the top of the page, then the table with the packages and at the bottom the full content of the overview.

Is there a way, to have the full content of the overview to appear on top of the generated output?

Comment: Maybe, but you shouldn't. The Javadoc is formatted uniformly across all APIs. Don't try to be special. The first sentence should explain what the package/method is in one sentence.

Comment: In general you are right. Still, i want to point the reader to some important information, and when it is hidden down the page, it will be missed easily.  
Then the only chance it to use the single first sentence and make it `<strong>`.

Comment: If it's important information then tell the user that there is important information in the full description. Don't give too many details in the one-liner.